# Debugging memory problems in java - understanding freeMemory

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have an application that causes an OutOfMemoryError, so I try to debug it using Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(). Here is what I get:

```
freeMemory=48792216
 ## Reading real sentences file...map size=4709. freeMemory=57056656
 ## Reading full sentences file...map size=28360. freeMemory=42028760
freeMemory=42028760
 ## Reading suffix array files of main corpus ...array size=513762 freeMemory=90063112
 ## Reading reverse suffix array files... array size=513762. freeMemory=64449240
```

I try to understand the behaviour of freeMemory. It starts with 48 MB, then - after I read a large file - it jumps UP to 57 MB, then down again to 42 MB, then - after I read a very large file (513762 elements) it jumps UP to 90 MB, then down again to 64 MB.

What happens here? How can I make sense of these numbers?

Comment: Just a short background - I deploy my application in Google App Engine, and the OutOfMemory error is only on production, not on my own computer. So I try to understand where the memory goes.

Comment: Have you set any parameters for total heap to your app like Xmx and Xms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java memory is a bit tricky. Your program runs inside the JVM, the JVM runs inside the OS, the OS uses your computer resources. When your program needs memory, the JVM will see if it has already requested to the OS some memory that is currently unused, if there isn't enough memory, the JVM will ask the OS and, if possible, obtain some memory.

From time to time, the JVM will look around for memory that is not used anymore, and will free it. Depending on a (huge) number of factors, the JVM can also give that memory back to the OS, so that other programs can use it.

This mean that, at any given moment, you have a certain quantity of memory the JVM has obtained from the OS, and a certain amount the JVM is currently using.

At any given point, the JVM may refuse to acquire more memory, because it has been instructed to do so, or the OS may deny the JVM to access to more memory, either because again instructed to do so, or simply because there is no more free RAM.

When you run your program on your computer, you are probably not giving any limit to the JVM, so you can use plenty of RAM. When running on google apps, there could be some limits imposed to the JVM by google operators, so that available memory may be less.

Runtime.freeMemory will tell you how much of the RAM the JVM has obtained from the OS is currently free.

When you allocate a big object, say one MB, the JVM may require more RAM to the OS, say 5 MB, resulting in freeMemory be 4 MB more than before, which is counterintuitive. Allocating another MB will probably shrink free memory as expected, but later the JVM could decide to release some memory to the OS, and freeMemory will shrink again with no apparent reason.

Using totalMemory and maxMemory in combination with freeMemory you can have a better insight of your current RAM limits and consumption.

To understand *why* you are consuming more RAM than you would expect, you should use a memory profiler. A simple but effective one is packaged with VisualVM, a tool usually already installed with the JDK. There you'll be able to see what is using RAM in your program and why that memory cannot be reclaimed by the JVM.

(Note, the memory system of the JVM is by far more complicated than this, but I hope that this simplification can help you understand more than a complete and complicated picture.)

Answer (score 4):

It's not terribly clear or user friendly. If you look at the runtime api you see 3 different memory calls:

> freeMemory Returns the amount of free memory in the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Calling the gc method may result in increasing the value
>   returned by freeMemory.
>
> totalMemory Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual
>   machine. The value returned by this method may vary over time,
>   depending on the host environment.
>
> maxMemory Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual
>   machine will attempt to use.

When you start up the jvm, you can set the initial heap size (-Xms) as well as the max heap size (-Xmx). e.g. java -Xms100m -Xmx 200m starts with a heap of 100m, will grow the heap as more space is needed up to 200, and will fail with OutOfMemory if it needs to grow beyond that. So there's a ceiling, which gives you maxMemory().

The memory currently available in the JVM is somewhere between your starting and max. Somwhere. That's your totalMemory(). freeMemory() is how much is free out of that total.

To add to the confusion, see what they say about gc - "Calling the gc method may result in increasing the value returned by freeMemory." This implies that uncollected garbage is *not* included in free memory.

Comment: And of course calling `gc` is just a suggestion...the VM may very well decide it doesn't feel like `gc`ing at the present time...

Answer (score 3):

OK, based on your comments I wrote this function, which prints a summary of memory measures:

```
static String memory() {
    final int unit = 1000000; // MB
    long usedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    long availableMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - usedMemory;
    return "Memory: free="+(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/unit)+" total="+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/unit)+" max="+(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/unit+" used="+usedMemory/unit+" available="+availableMemory/unit);
}
```

It seems that the best measures for how much my program is using are usedMemory, and the complementary availableMemory. They increase/decrease monotonically when I use more memory:

```
Memory: free=61 total=62 max=922 used=0 available=921
Memory: free=46 total=62 max=922 used=15 available=906
Memory: free=46 total=62 max=922 used=15 available=876
Memory: free=44 total=118 max=922 used=73 available=877
Memory: free=97 total=189 max=922 used=92 available=825
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running your app against something like http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html.
It comes with the JVM (or certainly used to) and is invaluable in terms of monitoring what is happening inside the JVM during the execution of an applicaiton.

It'll provide more of a useful insight as to what is going on with regards to your memory than your debug statements.

Also, if you are really keen, you can learn a bit more about tuning garbage collections via something like;
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

This is pretty in depth, but it is good to get an insight into the various generations of memory in the JVM and how objects are retained in these generations. If you are seeing that objects are being retained in old gen and old gen is continually increasing, then this could be an indicator of a leak.

For debugging why data is being retained and not collected, then you can't go past profilers. Check out JProfiler or Yourkit.

Best of luck.